# Find all file paths from a list of strings

Tags: c#, list, file, path

I am trying to find all file paths in a list of strings. The problem is this list is containing normal words, urls and paths how can i only get the paths. Does anyone have an idea. The list allTags contains all values of the yaml file. The user will enter the path of his project and i need to check if the defined paths are existing. for example the pattern cant be a path so i need to create a function which only check the values which are a path

```
gc:
  - clean:
      - location: build/buildresults/
        pattern: '*'
    dependencies:
      location: build/settings/targets
  - solution:
      results: build/buildresults/
      framework: ''
    test:
      configuration: Release
      results: build/testresults/Release/windows/

    public void CheckIfPathExists(string projectPath, List<Tuple<string, string>> allTags)
    {
        foreach (var Tag in allTags)
        {
            var configurationValue = Tag.Item2;
            configurationValue = projectpath + configurationValue;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Search for valid path C# and you find the questions that will help. [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-5.0) and the `FileInfo`-constructor(with a try-catch) is what you are looking for

Comment: I habe edited the question maybe now its more clear what i want